# How to make sure that user has clicked on textarea using php

Tags: php

I know that we can check if button is clicked or not in php but is there any way we can check if textarea is focused or not in php without using jquery or Javascript only using php

Comment: No. PHP is server-side, not client side. You'd have to have JavaScript send an AJAX request to a PHP script on your server upon the focusing of the text area. So basically: user clicks textures, JavaScript AJAX call to PHP file, PHP file returns something for JavaScript to act upon

Answer (score 1):

PHP runs on the server, it has no knowledge of what's happening in the client's browser. The only reason you can check if a button has been clicked is because when the browser sends the form data to the server, it includes the name of the button that was clicked. Also note that this only works on buttons that actually trigger a form submission, you can't detect any old button press with PHP.

Since focusing on a textarea doesn't submit anything to the server, no PHP code is even run, so there isn't any way to do what you want. Javascript is the only solution, since it runs in the client's browser, not on the server.